# Java selenium test is failing in Chrome 122 in --headless=new mode. But it's passing when --headless=new is removed

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

In a project, I use selenium and webdrivermanager to run tests. After the latest update in selenium(4.18.1) and webdrivermanager(5.7.0). I've realized that one test is failing.

When I remove the "--headless=new" from switches and run the test again, then it's passing. When I add the "--headless=new" flag again, it fails and I could not find anything useful in the logs. My test is about playing a video. I think there may be some performance optimizations in Chrome 122 that may cause this problem.

Is there anyone who knows what the difference is in Chrome 122?

Chrome switches are

```
Arrays.asList("--disable-extensions",
            "--disable-gpu", 
            "--headless=new",
            "--disable-web-security",
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
            "--log-level=1",
            "--remote-allow-origins=*",
            "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream",
            "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream",
            "--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://" + SERVER_ADDR + ",http://" + SERVER_ADDR + ":5080"
            );
```

### Update: Workaround Solution

I've figured out that following line cause the problem

```
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
```

When I switch it to WINDOW, the test is passing

```
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.WINDOW);
```